# Has anyone used Juxtapose? How good is it?

Tags: java, p2p

I'm thinking about using Juxtapose for a simple peer-to-peer game.  How good is Juxtapose?  How complicated is it?

Answer (score 1):

The JXTA community has released version 2.6 & 2.7 recently. It is significantly more stable and tested than release 2.5 and before. Check http://jxse.kenai.com for a start, you will find the information you need. You can also read the Practical JXTA II book online at Scribd.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little complex, but clearly worth it.

Comment: Changed "worst" to "worth", I assume it wasn't word-play.